# Unhandled exception when assigning new values?

Tags: c, linked-list

I am learning about Linked Lists and wanted to make a struct representation of a polynomial. The creation, insertion, and deletion of the nodes work fine, but when trying to copy values from one polynomial into a resulting one, I get hit with `Unhandled exception ... Access reading violation` error. Why is this function causing this?

```
struct Fraction {
    int num;
    int denom;
};

struct PolyTerm {
    int exp;
    struct Fraction* coe;
};

struct PolyList {
    struct PolyTerm* polyTerm;
    struct PolyList* next;
};

typedef struct Fraction Fraction;
typedef struct PolyTerm PolyTerm;
typedef struct PolyList PolyList;

PolyList* test(PolyList* list1, PolyList* list2) {
    PolyList* result = (PolyList*)malloc(sizeof(PolyList));

    result->polyTerm->exp = (list2)->polyTerm->coe;
    result->polyTerm->coe = (list1)->polyTerm->coe;

    return result;
}
```

I've ran the code through the debugger and this is the line the program breaks at.

```
result->polyTerm->exp = (list2)->polyTerm->coe;
```

Here is my stack trace

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00DC290A in PolyFun.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xCDCDCDCD.
```

Comment: Show us the definition of your `struct`.

Comment: I think you may find some insight into [magic number debug values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Magic_debug_values) rather telling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you allocate the memory for the `PolyList` structure, it only allocates memory for that structure. The members of that structure are not initialized, and pointers will not point to any valid memory, so when you dereference `result->polyTerm` you are dereferencing an uninitialized pointer (whose value is *indeterminate*) leading to *undefined behavior* and a likely crash.

You need to initialize the structure, including making pointers in it point to valid memory.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I managed to fix it by correctly initializing `result`.